# Find characters inside quotation marks in String

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I'm trying to pull out the parts of a string that are in quotation marks, i.e. in `"Rouge One" is an awesome movie` I want to extract Rouge One.

This is what I have so far but can't figure out where to go from here: I create a copy of the text so that I can remove the first quotation mark so that I can get the index of the second.

```
if text.contains("\"") {
    guard let firstQuoteMarkIndex = text.range(of: "\"") else {return}
    var textCopy = text
    let textWithoutFirstQuoteMark = textCopy.replacingCharacters(in: firstQuoteMarkIndex, with: "")
    let secondQuoteMarkIndex = textCopy.range(of: "\"")
    let stringBetweenQuotes = text.substring(with: Range(start: firstQuoteMarkIndex, end: secondQuoteMarkIndex))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rouge = "\"Rouge One\" is an awesome movie"

var separated = rouge.components(separatedBy: "\"") // ["", "Rouge One", " is an awesome movie"]

separated.dropFirst().first
```

Comment: All great answers but this was the most lightweight that fulfilled by needs.  Thank you!

Comment: @GarySabo **in general** bare in mind this answer returns an optional + it doesn't check if you have 2 separators. It's a dirty but lightweight answer. It would be best to check with something like a simple `if separated.count >2 {rest of the code}`. Or simply do what other answers are doing :D

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create copies or to replace substrings for this task.
Here is a possible approach:

- Use `text.range(of: "\"")` to find the first quotation mark.
- Use `text.range(of: "\"", range:...)` to find the second quotation mark, i.e. the first one *after* the range found in step 1.
- Extract the substring between the two ranges.

Example:

```
let text = "  \"Rouge One\" is an awesome movie"

if let r1 = text.range(of: "\""),
    let r2 = text.range(of: "\"", range: r1.upperBound..<text.endIndex) {

    let stringBetweenQuotes = text.substring(with: r1.upperBound..<r2.lowerBound)
    print(stringBetweenQuotes) // "Rouge One"
}
```

Another option is a regular expression search with "positive lookbehind" and "positive lookahead" patterns:

```
if let range = text.range(of: "(?<=\\\").*?(?=\\\")", options: .regularExpression) {
    let stringBetweenQuotes = text.substring(with: range)
    print(stringBetweenQuotes)
}
```

Comment: Good use of lookahead/lookbehind. But, what about a string like `"a"b"`? Should both be matched?

Comment: @jtbandes: That code would extract the string between the first two quotation marks (which is how I understood the question). If *all* quoted strings are wanted then your approach is better.

Comment: You forgot to unwrap `r2` when doing `r2.lowerBound`. it should be `r2!.lowerBound`. Though I don't understand why I can't do `r2?.lowerBound`

Comment: @Honey: No. Both `r1` and `r2` are assigned with optional binding. If the second range is `nil` then the if-block will not be executed.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `,` :D

Comment: how can I use this on a sentence which has multiple quoted words?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [regular expressions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression) to find pairs of quotes:

```
let pattern = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\"([^\"]+)\\\"")

// Small helper methods making it easier to work with enumerateMatches(in:...)
extension String {
    subscript(utf16Range range: Range<Int>) -> String? {
        get {
            let start = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
            let end = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
            return String(utf16[start..<end])
        }
    }

    var fullUTF16Range: NSRange {
        return NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count)
    }
}

// Loop through *all* quoted substrings in the original string.
let str = "\"Rogue One\" is an awesome movie"
pattern.enumerateMatches(in: str, range: str.fullUTF16Range) { (result, flags, stop) in
    // rangeAt(1) is the range representing the characters in the 1st
    // capture group of the regular expression: ([^"]+)
    if let result = result, let range = result.rangeAt(1).toRange() {
        print("This was in quotes: \(str[utf16Range: range] ?? "<bad range>")")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use .components(separatedBy:)

```
let stringArray = text.components(separatedBy: "\"")
```

Check if stringArray count is > 2 (there is at least 2 quotes).

Check if stringArray count is odd, aka count % 2 == 1.

- If it is odd, all the even indices are between 2 quotes and they are what you want.
- If it is even, all the even indices - 1 are between 2 quotes (the last one doesn't have an end quote).

This will allow you to also capture multiple sets of quoted strings, like:
"Rogue One" is a "Star Wars" movie.